# How do you access other class methods and functions using Kivy GUI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

I'm using python and kivy to write an app. For simplicity, I want to find a way to switch between screens without having to declare a function to go to a screen in every single class.

For example, in my UserLogin class, I define a function called `to_mainmenu` that can be used to go back to the EntryScreen widget. I want to use that function in the MainScreen widget in the corresponding KV file, specifically for the button that says 'option', but because it was declared in another class, I don't know the syntax to call `to_mainmenu` within that kv file. How can I call it?

Below is the python code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


kivy.require('1.11.1')


class EntryScreen(GridLayout):

    def to_newuser(self):
        main_app.screen_manager.current = 'New Account'
        # yes

    def to_userlogin(self):
        main_app.screen_manager.current = 'User Login'

    def to_mainmenu(self):
        main_app.screen_manager.current = 'Main Screen'


class UserLogin(GridLayout):
    name1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    password1 = ObjectProperty(None)

    def to_entryscreen(self):
        main_app.screen_manager.current = 'Entry Screen'

    def to_login(self):
        main_app.screen_manager.current = 'Login Screen'

    def to_mainscreen(self):
        main_app.screen_manager.current = 'Main Screen'


class NewAccount(GridLayout):
    def to_mainmenu(self):
        main_app.screen_manager.current = 'Main Screen'


class MainScreen(GridLayout):
    pass


class MapGem(App):
    def build(self):
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()

        self.entry_screen = EntryScreen()
        screen = Screen(name='Entry Screen')
        screen.add_widget(self.entry_screen)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        self.user_login = UserLogin()
        screen = Screen(name='User Login')
        screen.add_widget(self.user_login)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        self.new_account = NewAccount()
        screen = Screen(name='New Account')
        screen.add_widget(self.new_account)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        self.mainscreen = MainScreen()
        screen = Screen(name='Main Screen')
        screen.add_widget(self.mainscreen)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        return self.screen_manager


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_app = MapGem()
    main_app.run()
```

Below is the kivy file

```
<EntryScreen>
    cols: 1
    
    Button:
        text: 'New User'
        on_press: root.to_newuser()
        
    Button:
        text: 'Login'
        on_press: root.to_userlogin()
        
    Button:
        text: 'Skip Login'
        on_press:
            #root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
            root.to_mainmenu()
        

<UserLogin>
    name1: name
    password1: password
    cols: 2

    Label:
        text: 'Login to Account'

    Label:
        text: ''
    
    Label:
        text: 'Username'

    TextInput:
        id: name
        multiline: False
        
    Label:
        text: 'Password'

    TextInput:
        id: password
        multiline: False
        password: True
        
    Button:
        text: 'Submit'
        on_press: root.to_mainscreen()
    Button:
        text: 'Go back to Entry Screen'
        on_press: root.to_entryscreen()


<NewAccount>
    cols: 2
    Label:
        text: 'Create New Account'
    Label:
        text: ''
        
    Label:
        text: 'Username'

    TextInput:
        multiline: False
    
    Label:
        text: 'Password'

    TextInput:
        multiline: False
        password: True

    Button:
        text: 'Submit'
        on_press: root.to_mainmenu()
    

<MainScreen>
    cols: 1

    Button:
        text: 'Create New Maps'

    Button:
        text: 'View Maps'

    Button:
        text: 'Options'
        # on_press: something to call UserLogin.to_entryscreen()
```

I'm still getting used to how kivy handles OOP and what root, app, and other names mean. So, I'm sure this is a very basic and easy question, so I apologize ahead of time if it seems mundane.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a way. I reread the documentation and figured out that I had to use what my screen manager used to refer back to the instance of each class. so, simply put, I used `on_press: app.user_login.to_entryscreen()` to call the function that I needed. The complete code is posted below.

Python:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


kivy.require('1.11.1')


class EntryScreen(GridLayout):

    def to_newuser(self):
        main_app.screen_manager.current = 'New Account'
        # yes

    def to_userlogin(self):
        main_app.screen_manager.current = 'User Login'

    def to_mainmenu(self):
        main_app.screen_manager.current = 'Main Screen'


class UserLogin(GridLayout):
    name1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    password1 = ObjectProperty(None)

    def to_entryscreen(self):
        main_app.screen_manager.current = 'Entry Screen'

    def to_login(self):
        main_app.screen_manager.current = 'Login Screen'

    def to_mainscreen(self):
        main_app.screen_manager.current = 'Main Screen'


class NewAccount(GridLayout):
    def to_mainmenu(self):
        main_app.screen_manager.current = 'Main Screen'


class MainScreen(GridLayout):
    pass


class MapGem(App):
    def build(self):
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()

        self.entry_screen = EntryScreen()
        screen = Screen(name='Entry Screen')
        screen.add_widget(self.entry_screen)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        self.user_login = UserLogin()
        screen = Screen(name='User Login')
        screen.add_widget(self.user_login)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        self.new_account = NewAccount()
        screen = Screen(name='New Account')
        screen.add_widget(self.new_account)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        self.mainscreen = MainScreen()
        screen = Screen(name='Main Screen')
        screen.add_widget(self.mainscreen)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        return self.screen_manager


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_app = MapGem()
    main_app.run()
```

KV:

```
<EntryScreen>
    cols: 1
    
    Button:
        text: 'New User'
        on_press: root.to_newuser()
        
    Button:
        text: 'Login'
        on_press: root.to_userlogin()
        
    Button:
        text: 'Skip Login'
        on_press:
            #root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
            root.to_mainmenu()
        

<UserLogin>
    name1: name
    password1: password
    cols: 2

    Label:
        text: 'Login to Account'

    Label:
        text: ''
    
    Label:
        text: 'Username'

    TextInput:
        id: name
        multiline: False
        
    Label:
        text: 'Password'

    TextInput:
        id: password
        multiline: False
        password: True
        
    Button:
        text: 'Submit'
        on_press: root.to_mainscreen()
    Button:
        text: 'Go back to Entry Screen'
        on_press: root.to_entryscreen()


<NewAccount>
    cols: 2
    Label:
        text: 'Create New Account'
    Label:
        text: ''
        
    Label:
        text: 'Username'

    TextInput:
        multiline: False
    
    Label:
        text: 'Password'

    TextInput:
        multiline: False
        password: True

    Button:
        text: 'Submit'
        on_press: root.to_mainmenu()
    

<MainScreen>
    cols: 1

    Button:
        text: 'Create New Maps'

    Button:
        text: 'View Maps'

    Button:
        text: 'Options'
        on_press: app.user_login.to_entryscreen()
```